# count Number of days between two jquery datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

I've been tried for count days between two datepicker using this script, and it was successful.

```
$("#jqxDateTimeInput1").jqxDateTimeInput({
    width: '250px',
    height: '25px',
    showTimeButton: true,
    formatString: "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt",
    theme: 'energyblue'
});

$("#jqxDateTimeInput2").jqxDateTimeInput({
    width: '250px',
    height: '25px',
    showTimeButton: true,
    formatString: "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt",
    theme: 'energyblue'
});

$("#jqxBTN").jqxButton({
    width: '250px',
    height: '25px',
    theme: 'energyblue'
});

$("#jqxBTN").on("click", function(){
    var date1 = $('#jqxDateTimeInput1').val('date');
    var date2 = $('#jqxDateTimeInput2').val('date');
    var difference = date2 - date1;

    alert("The difference ini milliseconds: " + difference);
});
```

But I need this script for counting days between two date, is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a simple calculation like that;

```
$("#jqxBTN").on("click", function(){

  var date1 = $('#jqxDateTimeInput1').val('date');
  var date2 = $('#jqxDateTimeInput2').val('date');
  var difference = date2 - date1;

  var differenceInDays = Math.ceil(difference/(1000 * 3600 * 24)); //Day calculation

  alert("The difference in days: " + differenceInDays);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are receiving the inputs (date1 and date2) in epoch or can convert it into epoch. Then difference obtained is actually in seconds.

You can then divide it by 86400.

Here is the script, assuming the parameters to be in epoch.

```
public function countDays($day1Epoch, $day2Epoch)
{
    $secondsInDay = 86400;

    $day1 = $day1Epoch/$secondsInDay; // This will give you only the day count, excluding the time variable.
    $day2 = $day2Epoch/$secondsInDay;

    $countDays = $day2 - $day2;

    return $countDays;
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Can you please also give a reason for downvote, I will try to correct it next time.